What is more important: observing the fast of Gedalia or taking care of one's children?
If fasting on the fast of Gedalia makes a mother too weak to care for her kids - should she fast?

Same question could be asked about a father

There is an additional heter for a mother ... many consider them to be "in recovery mode" for 2 or even 3 years after having a baby. Which is why many women haven't fasted minor fasts for a solid 10+ years straight.

It's not a question of "which is more important." We don't play those games.
The better question to ask is: was this person included in the enactment of the fast to begin with? This is a minor fast, and only ever intended for "the well and able-bodied."
If someone can fast but will need to lie down and find a babysitter for their kids, and can do so, that's fine. If fasting puts them in a situation where they are physically not coping ... or there's no one else around to keep the kids from setting the house on fire, and tending to them while fasting makes the parent feel ill ... then we fall back on the "never included in the mitzvah to fast" category. (In which case it's not that some other value is better than fasting, it's that there's no obligation to fast.)
This really needs to be discussed with a competent rabbi, by the way.
